# Problem when creating a new chat room and associating it with a specific SE site

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

On [UX.SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com), someone was given the advice to move a discussion to chat, and when he tried, he said this:

> @charles if this site allowed the question "worst web interface" my answer would be the SE chat! Confusing interface, terminology, purpose... I create a room specify it is for the UX site, and after submission gets assigned to serverfault.

I went out to try this and created the following chat room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/961/test-ux-room

When I created it, I switched the Related Site to "User Experience" but it still got created as a SO chat room. It looks like it is not honoring what is selected on that screen for the related site.

**Update** - It looks like the chat rooms might just be using the site associated with the chat account being used to create the chat room.

**Additionally** - There are two "Stack Exchange Network" sites listed, currently.

[image: Duplicate Stack Exchange Sites to Associate With]

Comment: I am not sure if this is the reason of the issue, but the parent user associated with your chat account is the one you have on Stack Overflow; I created a room associated with Drupal Answers, and my parent account is the one on Drupal Answers.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - I was thinking that that might be the cause as well. I just checked the user that posted that comment, and his chat account is associated with ServerFault as well.

Comment: I can confirm; I created a room, and tried to associate it with Stack Overflow, but it has been associated with Drupal Answers, even though I was able to select Stack Overflow. Still, I would consider it a bug, if I can select an SE site for which I cannot associate any room. If the rooms I create are only associated with the SE site for which I selected my parent user, then I should not be able to select a different SE site.

Comment: Maybe moderators can create a room and associate it with every SE site; if that is the case, it would be easy to first verify if the user is a moderator in any SE site.

Comment: Some time ago I tried to create a room for the "Facebook's 'Awesome' Announcements" event, and associated it with Web Apps, but after the fact it was bound to Ask Different. I'm glad to see that I wasn't just crazy :).

Comment: As an update, I'm about to push the fix for creation - it related to the "looks like something similar already exists" bounce in the middle. If you didn't get the bounce, it worked. With the bounce: not so much.

Answer (score 5):

If the site association has been done incorrectly, that sounds like a bug. We'll fix that. Likewise the duplicated SE.