# Moving a discussion to chat reloads all chatrooms and changes profile picture

Tags: bug, chat, linked-accounts, profile-picture, chat-profile

## Short version

Today I had some extensive discussions in comments and was offered to take the discussion to a chatroom¹. When I clicked the link, the following happened (in addition the expected behaviour):

- A reload was triggered in all tabs with open chatrooms.
- My avatar in all chatrooms changed to the one I use on the site from which the chatroom was generated. This phenomenon was visible to other users.

## Long version

My profile pictures on German Language, Super User and Graphic Design are (in the that order):

[image: yellow and purple] [image: blue and black] [image: teal and pink]

My chat account is associated to my account on German language and I usually see the first picture as my chat avatar.

1. Today I had a long comment discussion on Super User, got the notice¹ and clicked the link. I had several chatrooms open in other tabs at that time and they all reloaded. Moreover, my avatar (as shown to me) changed to the Super User one.
2. At about the same time, I had a discussion on Graphic Design that escalated as well, and clicked the link there (about ten minutes later). Again, all chatrooms reloaded and my avatar changed to the one from Graphic Design. But not everywhere, in some chatrooms, the Super User avatar continued to be shown on old messages:

[image: That happened]

A few minutes later, the avatar on the old message changed to the Graphic Design colours as well, so I blame caching for that (but maybe it helps to locate the bug).

I asked other chat users how they saw my avatar, and they all saw the Graphic Design one.

3. While I was writing these lines, everything changed back to normal (German Language) – for me and apparently everybody else.

Note that all changes applied to my [chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/68718/wrzlprmft) as well. I also experienced this before, but only now I am sure that the comments-to-chat mechanism is the culprit.

In case it matters, all of this happened in Firefox 47.0.

Finally, the problem may be related to the one described in these questions:

- [Moving a comment chain to chat temporarily disables chat moderator privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113207/255554)
- [Unwanted feature: chat account auto-re-parenting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110188/255554)
- [Problem when creating a new chat room and associating it with a specific SE site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100534/255554)

---

<sup>¹ Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?</sup>

Comment: I never noticed that (a) that was an apple (with a leaf) or (b) that the top and bottom "circle-like blobs" weren't the same until you posted these large images.  TIL. :-)